# How to close a blocked socket

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets

A windows service has an open socket that is receiving data (on a separate thread)

In response to the service `OnShutdown` I would like to signal worker thread to shutdown, but it's currently blocked on the `Receive`.

At the moment I'm timing out on the `Receive` to check if there is a stop request pending.  Is there a better approach, rather than waiting on the timeout to notify the worker thread to stop receiving and go through its shutdown logic?

Comment: The best approach is to use asynchronous sockets. They scale much better anyway.

Comment: In a sense it is async.  Granted I'm not using BeginReceive -- but even if I was, how would I get that thread to stop Receiving while it's waiting on data.

Answer (score 2):

Call `Socket.Close`. It will cause the `Socket.Receive` method to throw an exception unblocking it immediately.

The exception is an IO.IOException, that has an SocketException as an inner exception. The native error code of the inner exception is 10004.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Interrupt() on the thread should make it break out of any blocking operation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx

Note that this will cause a `ThreadInterruptedException` (when blocking), which you should handle appropriately.

Comment: that would be great, but it seems that the thread is not blocked by the Socket.Receive in such a way that this interrupt ever gets heard.